# Update native library without reinstalling the app

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have app which include two native library (for example libfirst.so, libsecond.so). Now a loading libraries standard method.

```
System.loadLibrary("first");
System.loadLibrary("second");
```

Now I need to be able to update the library without reinstalling the app (without update .apk).
I can loaded native libraries this method

```
System.load("/storage/emulated/0/armeabi/libfirst.so");
System.load("/storage/emulated/0/armeabi/libsecond.so");
```

I think this is a bad practice.
I tried to copy manual the libraries in folder getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir , but system error:
 *open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)*


What are the best practices update native libraries without update apk ?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the best practices update native libraries without update apk ?

I don't believe that contingency is covered.

Code signing does two things. First, it ensures the developer who publishes the app is the same one who updates the app. Second, it creates trust relationships between related apps (but that does not apply here). Nikolay Elenkov discusses the topic at [Code signing in Android's security model](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/05/code-signing-in-androids-security-model.html).

If you want to update the dependent libraries, then you need to rebuild the APK to prove you are authorized to make the updates. That's part one of code signing discussed above.

If you want to update a personal copy of the app (and not publish it), then just strip the existing signatures, update the libraries, sign with the [Debug signing key](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), and then push to the device.

Also, you are safe to perform `adb install -r <the apk>`. `-r` is *"replace existing application"*, and its effectively a reinstall. It retains the previous application data, like a database.

There are some other things that need to be done when updating an app, like increasing version numbers so its handled properly in Google Play. But they are not really relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do it

for install your apk:

```
adb install -r path_to_my_apk.apk
```

now you can change your code and recompile your .so and when you want to update it you can do:

```
adb push -p path_to_my_so.so /data/local/tmp/libmyso.so
adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/libmyso.so | run-as com.mycomp.myapp sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.mycomp.myapp/lldb/libmyso.so; chmod 700 /data/data/com.mycomp.myapp/lldb/libmyso.so'
adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/libmyso.so
```

Android studio does exactly this in order to install the lldb server when you are debugging native code.
It assumes there is a folder called lldb in your app directory. if you are debugging using Android Studio, this folder will already be there.

Your Java code needs to make sure to load the correct .so using

```
System.load("/data/data/com.mycomp.myapp/lldb/libmyso.so");
```

Instead of `System.loadLibrary()` which doesn't take a full path in a static initialization block somewhere, similar to how you load any other .so

This method can be very useful if your apk is huge and you only want to update the binary for easy debugging.